# Livekit host audio error in React and NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webrtc, livekit

I am trying to implement video-calling an live-streaming in my `nextjs` project using Livekit (webrtc stack). Currently, I am facing the audio issue, where users can't hear audio from the user who create the video-calling event. I have check if that users audio not getting fine but the local audio tracks are fine. Anyone can tell me whats going on here?
Please find the code for reference

this is the livekit component that I used in my main component:

```
<LiveKitRoom
    url={url}
    token={token}
    onConnected={handleOnConnected}
    roomOptions={{
        adaptiveStream: true,
        dynacast: true,
        publishDefaults: {
            simulcast: true,
        },
        videoCaptureDefaults: {
            resolution: VideoPresets.h720.resolution,
        },
        audioCaptureDefaults: {
            autoGainControl: true,
            echoCancellation: true,
            noiseSuppression: true,
         },
     }}
     connectOptions={{
         autoSubscribe: true,
     }}
     controlRenderer={({ room }) => {
          return (
               <>     
                  <ControlsView
                      room={room}
                      enableScreenShare={true}
                      enableAudio={true}
                      enableVideo={true}
                      onLeave={() => {
                         room.disconnect()
                         setEnd(true)
                         props.setIsEndParent(true)
                       }}
                   />
               </>
           );
      }}
    onLeave={onLeave}
/>
```

for generating the `token` I am using the following function:

```
createToken(createTokenDTO) {
    try {
      const roomName = createTokenDTO.roomName;
      const participantName = createTokenDTO.participant;

      const at = new AccessToken(
        process.env.LIVEKIT_API_KEY,
        process.env.LIVEKIT_SECRET,
        {
          identity: participantName,
        },
      );
      const grantPermission = {
        ...createTokenDTO,
        room: roomName,
        roomJoin: true,
      };
      delete grantPermission.roomName;
      delete grantPermission.participant;
      at.addGrant(grantPermission);

      const token = at.toJwt();
      return token;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new HttpException(err, err.status || HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }
```